# MutationObserver on any active input field

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I was am developing a chrome extension that uses mutation observers to save + analyse the field.

For most sites id's stay the same but for Facebook, all ID's are generated with a unique key.

Is it possible to find the active input field and create a new observer based on that?

**ie.**

```
var uniqueID = //some function here to get current/highlighted input/textfield Selector

if (uniqueID != null) {
 new MutationObserver(function() {
   //do something...
 }).observe(uniqueID, {characterData: true, childList: true, subtree: true});
}
```

EDIT: no, this did not work unfortunately. Twitter, Facebook etc seem to use a mix of  and  as their input/input display

Here is an example of the Facebook selector:

"**#js_2k** > **div._i-o._2j7c** > div > **div.clearfix._ikh** > **div._4bl9** > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > span > span"

the **bolded** HTML is randomized every time the site loads

Comment: What about `uniqueID = document.querySelector('input:focus,textarea:focus');` ?

Comment: hmm, ill give it a try

Comment: Nope, did not work :(

Comment: That is a `span` not an `input` field

Comment: Facebook uses [content-editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) so I guess the selector should be `[contenteditable]` or something based on that.

Comment: `document.querySelector('[contenteditable]:focus')`

Comment: wOxxOm was right! that solved it thanks a bunch